# What's a word for someone who scoffs at someone else's feelings?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, nicknames

I am trying to find a word someone who ridicules someone else's feelings. When I say generally anything, they'll say something completely unnecessary (and usually hurtful). Most of the time, I am not even talking to them; they just jump into the conversation for no apparent nor helpful reason.

For example, if I say that I have my shoulder hurts, and they will scoff, thinking I am being fake and/or trying to get attention (which I never do; that's weird). There are also general instances where I will say that I don't like a certain food, and they will scoff and say that I always try to find something to complain about.

I also would like the verb form of what they are doing. For example: "This person _____(s) my feelings." I'm not sure if the word "belittle" is the right verb, but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: Is the behaviour such that it might be described as *boorish*? *Of, relating to, or characteristic of a boor or peasant; esp. rude, coarse; lacking in culture or refinement; ill-mannered, loutish.* (OED)

Comment: Is this bullying behaviour always towards the same person or is it to anyone and everyone?

Answer (score 1):

I would call them a poisoner, and an emotional bully.

Comment: Agreed! But if I were to put this in a formal report, I don't think using "prisoner" or "emotional bully" would be, well, formal. Any suggestions are welcome. =)

Answer (score 1):

I would say this person [derides](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deride) you.

MW.com:

> 1 : to laugh at or insult (contemptuously got derided by a carnival clown)

> 2 : to subject to usually bitter or contemptuous ridicule or criticism (politicians deriding their opponents)

> : to express a lack of respect or approval of (were derided as the weaker sex)

Their behavior could be described as *derisive* or [cantankerous](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/curmudgeon):

Lexico.com:

> Bad-tempered, argumentative, and uncooperative.

This person could be described as a [curmudgeon](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/curmudgeon)

MW.com

> 1 : a crusty, ill-tempered, and usually old man

> Crusty:  2 : giving an effect of surly incivility in address or disposition

Answer (score 1):

"This person hurts|dismisses|disparages|discounts| my feelings."

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that naming the behavior is a good idea. Describing the behavior is factual; it's not a matter of opinion (or libel).

From https://www.pirozinnalaw.com/blog/2018/09/phrase-letters-of-complaint-about-workplace-bullying-carefully/

> Here’s the most critical thing that you need to understand about
> workplace bullying: There is no law against it if it’s just general
> bad behavior. You are only legally protected from bullying as long as
> you are being targeted due to your race, religion, age, disability,
> national origin, gender or sexual orientation. Those are the
> categories that are legally protected from intimidation and
> harassment.
>
> What does that mean in practice? When you file a
> complaint, you want to make certain that you pinpoint exactly how the
> harassment you’re experiencing is related to one or more of those
> categories. That way, you cannot legally be retaliated against for
> reporting the bullying.
>
> Keep in mind, bullies are pretty much the same
> wherever you find them: they generally try to target people who are
> different in some way. The odds are high that you are being targeted
> due to some difference that falls into one or more of those protected
> categories. You simply have to make certain that you take pains to
> point that out in your complaint.

Answer (score 0):

This person is uncivil and hurts my feelings.  We are studying civility at work.  Usually, civility and politeness go hand in hand, but sometimes civility is a superset of politeness.